# Waiting for an process to quit in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, process, while-loop

Is there a possibility to wait for an process to quit, without it needs to running?
I know there is the keyword WaitForExit, but to use this the process needs to run.

My second question is, if there is a possibility to use an else-Statement in an while loop.
Tried it already, but it always said that there isnt an function called else.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time: the answers here are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do Until

```
Do {
    Sleep 5
} Until (Get-Process iexplore);
```

Will wait until iexplore is found

### While

```
While (Get-Process iexplore) {
    Sleep 5
}
```

Will wait until iexplore is no longer running

---

### Else after while

You cannot use an `else` statement after a `while` loop.

It needs to come after an `if`.

Comment: The Do Until Loop matches pretty well what i looked for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does it seems to fits your needs (1st question) ? http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849813.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a possibility to use an else-Statement in an while loop.

If you mean something like:

```
while (cond) {
} else {
}
```

?

Then NO. (how would the content of the `else` block be any different to code immediately following the `while` block?)

> Is there a possibility to wait for an process to quit,

Yes. There are different ways of doing this, depending on the nature of the target process. Is it one created by the same script? Is the same session? A service? Or just an arbitrary process?

Comment: 1. Ok, thats true. Didnt thought about that.
2. The process isnt created by the same script, its an arbitrary process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait-process cmdlet. 
Check link for details http://ss64.com/ps/wait-process.html

```
Example: wait-process -name notepad.exe
```