# Powershell script to wait for process to complete

Tags: powershell

I would like to create a script to check for a running process. If said process is running wait for it to complete before moving on to next step.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Waiting for an process to quit in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993797/waiting-for-an-process-to-quit-in-powershell). You are not really specific on what kind of process but that question covers some simple examples.

Answer (score 1):

`Wait-Process` should accomplish this. See the documentation at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849813.aspx.